# Pointer to short int in C

Tags: c, pointers

When I try to use a pointer to short, I get undefined behavior or segmentation fault.

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    short int *a;
    *a = 10;
    printf("%hd\n", *a);
    return 0;
}
```

Nothing is displayed on the command line.

So I can`t understand how can I properly work with it.

Comment: You must know more about pointers to understand it well.

Comment: If somebody gives you a blank piece of paper on which you can write a street address, do you automatically own a house?

Comment: Your compiler might give you some hint regarding "using variable a without assigning a value first". If not, you should increase warning level. If it does, don't ignore what your compiler tells you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because `a` is only a pointer but there is no memory allocated. It's also uninitialized, so reading it (`*a`) makes the program have undefined behavior.

You can `malloc` memory:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    short int *a = malloc(sizeof *a);
    if (a == NULL) return 1;

    *a = 10;
    printf("%hd\n", *a);

    free(a);
}
```

or make it point at an automatic variable:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    short int some_short_int; // automatic variable

    short int *a = &some_short_int;
    *a = 10;
    printf("%hd\n", some_short_int); // prints 10
}
```